# Matlab: Real negative odd roots

Tags: matlab

for any roots i need to create a script that the output will be only the real negative odd roots.

For example: `rtemp = [-8 -8 -8 -8 4 -1 3]`

to choose only real negative roots (there are some cases when the roots are complex, so i don't want complex roots :

```
rneg=[];
for i=1:length(rtemp)
    if(isreal(rtemp(i))==1) && (rtemp(i)<0)
        rneg = [rneg rtemp(i)];
    end
end

rneg =

    -8 -8 -8 -8 -1
```

Now i only want only the odd roots. In this example -8 is an even root (4 times) and -1 is odd, so the output will be only -1. If `rtemp = [-8 -8 -8 4 -1 3]`, the -8 will be an odd root (3 times) so the output will be `[-1 -8]`.
How can i write to have only the odd roots? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get negative real roots:

```
rneg = rtemp(imag(rtemp)==0 & real(rtemp) < 0)
```

Then to get only odd roots:

```
R = min(rneg):max(rneg);
final = R(mod(histc(rneg,R),2)==1)
```

Comment: +1 But note `isreal` detects type, not value. For example, `isreal(complex(1))` givers `false`. Depending on how the roots are obained, it may be safer to test `imag(rtemp)==0` instead of `isreal(rtemp)` (inspite of the problems associated with real-number comparison)

Comment: @LuisMendo You are right, also it looks like `isreal` doesn't return a vector plus `< 0` fails on a vector of complex numbers. Fixed now.